# How to set Page margin in reportviewer?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Here is my code, working but i am getting blank printing ?
I want set Top margin as 0 when i dont have Logo as Image.

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
pg.Margins.Top = 0;
pg.Margins.Bottom = 0;
pg.Margins.Left = 100;
pg.Margins.Right = 50;
System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
size.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4Extra;
pg.PaperSize = size;
reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);
```

Comment: You can do this in the report itself. Open the report in the report designer (Visual Studio) top menu bar "Report" -> "Report Properties" I believe. 
Do you do your "reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg)" after you load the report?

Comment: yes i have tried this before and after loading report same problem visualization is same as coding but printing is empty.

Answer (score 9):

you can do by the Page Settings or something like this..

```
var setup = frmReport.reportViewer1.GetPageSettings();           
setup.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(1, 1, 1, 1);
frmReport.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(setup);
```

Comment: The following does not work. I am using Visual Studio 2015. The error says **"ReportPageSetting.Margins can not be assigned to -- it is a read-only property"**

Comment: I've tried in vs2010 and 2015 without problem.. 
i gotta se if you're getting the correct property.
[link](https://i.imgur.com/3LxGsWU.png)